Why use linkedSignal instead of computed in Angular Signals?
I am trying to understand the differences between linkedSignal and computed in Angular's Signals system, and why linkedSignal would be preferred in certain situations.
For example, if I want to manage a selectedOption that depends on shippingOptions, why not use computed like this:
const shippingOptions = signal(['Ground', 'Air', 'Sea']);
const selectedOption = computed(() => shippingOptions()[0]);

Why linkedSignal is a better choice in scenarios like this?
I haven't tried implementing this yet—I'm trying to understand the conceptual differences between linkedSignal and computed. Based on what I understand, computed should work fine for dependent state. I'm wondering what makes linkedSignal a better option in Angular's Signals system.

A linkedSignal is a writable signal that is already derived from another reactive expression.
Indeed :
const selectedOption = linkedSignal(() => shippingOptions()[0]);

is the same as
const selectedOption = computed(() => shippingOptions()[0]);

in terms of reading the signal and reacting to its changes.
But linked signal is also a WritableSignal, so you can write to it locally.
const selectedOption = linkedSignal(() => shippingOptions()[0]);
selectionOption('myNewValue'). 

Also the computation of the linkedSignal allows to access previous values :
const selectedOption = linkedSignal({
  source: shippingOptions(),
  computation: (newValue, previousValue) => { value[0] }
});

One of the usecases for linkedSignal is a local state in a component that depends on an input() but that also be written from inside the component itself, without exposing the inner state unlike what model would do.

Not sure if this is clear for OP, it's not only input() signals that can be used - linkedSignal is also very handy for managing form data (initial values when you want to edit something for example).

LMAO I didn't see you answered your own question. So I think OP understood. ;)
